# How to list all children in Google Drive's appfolder and read file contents with Xamarin / c#?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to work with text files in the apps folder.

Here's my GoogleApiClient constructor:

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
   .AddApi(DriveClass.API)
   .AddScope(DriveClass.ScopeFile)
   .AddScope(DriveClass.ScopeAppfolder)
   .UseDefaultAccount()
   .AddConnectionCallbacks(this)
   .EnableAutoManage(this, this)
   .Build();
```

I'm connecting with:

```
googleApiClient.Connect()
```

And after:

```
OnConnected()
```

I need to list all files inside the app folder. Here's what I got so far:

```
    IDriveFolder appFolder = DriveClass.DriveApi.GetAppFolder(googleApiClient);
    IDriveApiMetadataBufferResult result = await appFolder.ListChildrenAsync(googleApiClient);
```

Which is giving me the files metadata.

But after that, I don't know how to read them, edit them or save new files. They are text files created with my app's previous version (native).

I'm following the google docs for drive but the Xamarin API is a lot different and has no docs or examples. Here's the API I'm using: https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleplayservices-drive

Edit:
Here is an example to read file contents from the guide:

```
    DriveFile file = ...
    file.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
        .setResultCallback(contentsOpenedCallback);
```

First I can't find anywhere in the guide what "DriveFile file = ..." means. How do I get this instance? DriveFile seems to be a static class in this API.
I tried:

```
IDriveFile file = DriveClass.DriveApi.GetFile(googleApiClient, metadata.DriveId);
```

This has two problems, first it complains that GetFile is deprecated but doesn't say how to do it properly. Second, the file doesn't have an "open" method.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Xamarin binding library wraps the Java Drive library (https://developers.google.com/drive/), so all the guides/examples for the Android-based Drive API work if you keep in mind the Binding's Java to C# transformations:

- get/set methods -> properties
- fields -> properties
- listeners -> events
- static nested class -> nested class
- inner class -> nested class with an instance constructor

So you can list the AppFolder's directory and files by recursively using the `Metadata` when the drive item is a folder.

#### Get Directory/File Tree Example:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    async void GetFolderMetaData(IDriveFolder folder, int depth)
    {
        var folderMetaData = await folder.ListChildrenAsync(_googleApiClient);
        foreach (var driveItem in folderMetaData.MetadataBuffer)
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, $"{(driveItem.IsFolder ? "(D)" : "(F)")}:{"".PadLeft(depth, '.')}{driveItem.Title}");
            if (driveItem.IsFolder)
                GetFolderMetaData(driveItem.DriveId.AsDriveFolder(), depth + 1);
        }
    }
    GetFolderMetaData(DriveClass.DriveApi.GetAppFolder(_googleApiClient), 0);
});
```

#### Output:

```
[SushiHangover.FlightAvionics] (D):AppDataFolder
[SushiHangover.FlightAvionics] (F):.FlightInstrumentationData1.json
[SushiHangover.FlightAvionics] (F):.FlightInstrumentationData2.json
[SushiHangover.FlightAvionics] (F):.FlightInstrumentationData3.json
[SushiHangover.FlightAvionics] (F):AppConfiguration.json
```

### Write a (Text) File Example:

```
using (var contentResults = await DriveClass.DriveApi.NewDriveContentsAsync(_googleApiClient))
using (var writer = new OutputStreamWriter(contentResults.DriveContents.OutputStream))
using (var changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
       .SetTitle("AppConfiguration.txt")
       .SetMimeType("text/plain")
       .Build())
{
    writer.Write("StackOverflow Rocks\n");
    writer.Write("StackOverflow Rocks\n");
    writer.Close();
    await DriveClass.DriveApi.GetAppFolder(_googleApiClient).CreateFileAsync(_googleApiClient, changeSet, contentResults.DriveContents);
}
```

Note: Substitute a `IDriveFolder` for `DriveClass.DriveApi.GetAppFolder` to save a file in a subfolder of the AppFolder.

### Read a (text) File Example:

Note: `driveItem` in the following example is an existing `text/plain`-based MetaData object that is found by recursing through the Drive contents (see Get Directory/File list above) or via creating a query (`Query.Builder`) and executing it via `DriveClass.DriveApi.QueryAsync`.

```
var fileContexts = new StringBuilder();
using (var results = await driveItem.DriveId.AsDriveFile().OpenAsync(_googleApiClient, DriveFile.ModeReadOnly, null))
using (var inputStream = results.DriveContents.InputStream)
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
{
    while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
        fileContexts.Append(await streamReader.ReadLineAsync());
}
Log.Debug(TAG, fileContexts.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm working with Xamarin for Android and my previous version was native, so I'm following the Java guide. I got this far. I managed to get the files metadata, but that is as far as I got. The API is not working. I'll edit the question with an example.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for this driveItem. I guess the main problem with the API is the quick help info is wrong. I'm used to type every variable, I avoid using "var" and that's why I was never able to compile. The description return type was never the right one. Gimme some time to try that out. Thanks again.

Comment: Works great, thanks! But I have another question if you don't mind. The API description says that I can save my files even if it's not connected that it will update them once connected. But I can't do anything with the _googleApiClient if disconnected. How is it?

Comment: @Dpedrinha You actually need a "connected" GoogleApiClient. Now, this does not mean a device that actually has any wifi/celluar data available, but you would still build a GoogleApiClient object and run `Connect()`, if the device has been previously authorized and synced in a prior connection, GoogleApiClient will actually "connect" and call the `OnConnected` listener and the `IsConnected` property will be true.

Comment: @Dpedrinha Now you have a valid GoogleApiClient object that can be used on your Drive calls and any existing files can be read. New files or changes to existing cached files will be sync'd when your device actually obtains a network connection.

Comment: I see. Thanks again. I guess I missed it because my device is not persisting its data between debug deploys. Great explanation and I believe it deserves a question. Want me to ask?

Comment: @Dpedrinha Under Xamarin Global Settings (Preferences / Projects / Android), *enable* `Preserve data/cache between application deploys`). This way when you are debugging across multiple sessions, your Drive "cache" will not be removed.

Comment: Thanks. But it is enabled. I even tried disabling and re-enabling. It's just not working. It doesn't persist anything. Not even files or preferences.

Comment: @Dpedrinha Strange.... works fine for me, not sure why it would not be working...

Comment: Me neither. Some people say I have to reset my device. I'm not willing to. It works if I install the release apk by myself though. Very weird.

Comment: Do you know the type to use for driveItem? I need to call methods passing driveItem but it never accepts the types I'm trying.

Comment: @Dpedrinha driveItem can be a IDriveFile, IDriveFolder, IDriveResource, .... depends upon what your item's metadata specifies are

Comment: Thanks. But I can't make it work. It doesn't accept me to cast to any of those, it accepts only MetadataBuffer, but then, the variable is always incomplete missing DriveId for instance.

Comment: @dpedrinha post a new question with what you are  trying to do

Comment: done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45725225/how-to-query-a-file-in-google-drive-for-xamarin-android-using-the-drive-api