# How to query an IDriveResource in Google Drive for Xamarin.Android using the Drive API?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get an IDriveResource in the Google Drive Apps Folder using a query, but I'm having trouble with type casting.
Here's the code I got so far:

```
using (IDriveFolder appFolder = DriveClass.DriveApi.GetAppFolder(googleApiClient))
using (QueryClass query = new QueryClass.Builder().AddFilter(Filters.Eq(SearchableField.Title, MY_FILE_NAME)).Build())
using (var queryResult = await appFolder.QueryChildrenAsync(googleApiClient, query))
using (var driveItem = queryResult.MetadataBuffer)
{
    using (var driveFile = await driveItem.DriveId.AsDriveFile().OpenAsync(googleApiClient, DriveFile.ModeWriteOnly, null))
    using (var outputStream = driveFile.DriveContents.OutputStream)
    using (var writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream))
    using (var changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                .SetLastViewedByMeDate(new Java.Util.Date())
                .Build())
    {
        writer.Write(MY_TEXT);
        writer.Close();
        driveFile.DriveContents.Commit(googleApiClient, changeSet);
    }
}
```

But the compiler doesn't recognize **DriveId** property in **driveItem**. I need to type cast **driveItem**, but the compiler won't accept any option. If it accepts on the **driveItem** declaration (like MetadataBuffer), it won't have the **DriveId** property. If I try IDriveFile or IDriveResource it won't accept the cast in the variable declaration.

I'm actually having the same problem when trying to pass **driveItem** to a method like:

```
private async Task<bool> saveDriveItem(???? driveItemToSave) 
{
   ...
}
```

I can't use this kind of method because I can't find the right ???? type to use.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MetadataBuffer` is a collection of Metadata entries and you are trying to use it as a singular `MetaData` object.

When you use a Drive query, you could get back multiple files/folders as Drive allows you to have multiple files with the same name even within the same folder.

Review all the results from your query:

```
using (IDriveFolder appFolder = DriveClass.DriveApi.GetAppFolder(googleApiClient))
using (QueryClass query = new QueryClass.Builder().AddFilter(Filters.Eq(SearchableField.Title, MY_FILE_NAME)).Build())
using (var queryResult = await appFolder.QueryChildrenAsync(googleApiClient, query))
{
    foreach (var driveItem in queryResult.MetadataBuffer)
    {
        Log.Debug("SO", driveItem.Title);   
    }
}
```

Since you are using `AppFolder` and only your app can write to it, *assumably* you only have one file with that unique file name unless your code is not checking for a pre-existing file and just writes a new one with the same name (which would be allowed).

Check for only one result in the `MetadataBuffer`, else log an error message:

```
using (IDriveFolder appFolder = DriveClass.DriveApi.GetAppFolder(googleApiClient))
using (QueryClass query = new QueryClass.Builder().AddFilter(Filters.Eq(SearchableField.Title, MY_FILE_NAME)).Build())
using (var queryResult = await appFolder.QueryChildrenAsync(googleApiClient, query))
{
    if (queryResult.MetadataBuffer.Count == 1)
    {
        var driveItem = queryResult.MetadataBuffer.Get(0) as Metadata;
        using (var driveFile = await driveItem.DriveId.AsDriveFile().OpenAsync(googleApiClient, DriveFile.ModeWriteOnly, null))
        {
            // do something with your drivefile...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Error("SO", $"The query for {MY_FILE_NAME} returned {queryResult.MetadataBuffer.Count} results?!?!?");
        // Your app is writing multiple files with the same name...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that the buffer can bring more than one file.

Comment: SushiHangover something really weird is going on here. My App uses only one xml file. If the file doesn't exist (queryResult.MetadataBuffer.Count == 0) it creates one. But every time I start my app it's creating a new one. queryResult is always returning 0 MetadataBuffer.Count. Do you know of any known bug while debuging on Android devices that could be doing it?

Comment: @Dpedrinha no, I basically do the same thing. If `Count` is zero on the query result, then that query/search resulted in nothing. Assuming you create a AppDrive-based file and it is synced, the app can be uninstalled/reinstalled/updated/... the query result should be `1`.

Comment: I know. But it's creating multiple files that look the same. I figured that it's a problem while debugging. Every time I debug, the query returns 0. But if I run the app without being attached to the debug, it gets the file. May have something to do with the fact that every time I debug, drive api asks for an account. But picking the same account should work even then. Looks like the query doesn't query the cloud, just local synced files. And that's why it's returning 0 files. It's not yet synced since I have to choose the account every time I debug, it's querying before syncing.