# How To upload Folder using Xamarin Android to google Drive

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-drive-android-api

Dears

I need to upload folder ( With the sub files ) from the mobile storage to Google drive

I added the needed reference 
and also I generated the Clien ID ( Google Drive Key ) from Google Console

What is the next step ?

Thanks in advance and sorry as I beginner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help to upload  file to Google drive.](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103015/help-to-upload-img-file-to-google-drive)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38434613/4984832

Answer (score 0):

**Read Quick Start on Google Android site.**

**When you are done with all the authentication process, go for How to upload file to Google Drive.**

*Edit*

**Reference Links**

https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/

Android Open and Save files to/from Google Drive SDK

http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/com/google/apis/google-api-services-drive/v2-rev9-1.8.0-beta/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback ,  but if there any suggestion using Xamarin Android instead of Java and it is highly appreciated if you there is an sample

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I stuck in the first line

[Please check this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrUOJ.jpg)