# Xamarin Native: How to connect to google drive and save a file

Tags: c#, xamarin, file-upload, xamarin.android, google-drive-android-api

I'm working on Xamarin Native app ( Not xamarin.Forms ) and I want the app to be able to connect to the google drive of any email e.g johndoe@gmail.com and save some files. I have searched to no avail but can't find an explicit example which uses Xamarin native to achieve that. Does anyone have some suggestions?

As suggested in the comment, I am not trying to connect to any email address, I'm trying to connect to the email address of the phone on which the app is running.

I installed the nuget package google.services.drive but I can't find any example of how to use the package. The one example i saw was using visual studio components which has now been depreciated in visual studio 2017/2019

Comment: You can not connect to just any Google account and upload a file, but you can connect to the Google registered account of the phone and upload a file to Drive : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432491/google-drive-api-implementation-xamarin-android/38434613#38434613

Comment: @SushiHangover yes that's what I was trying to achieve. I want to upload to the drive of the email registered on the android device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use Google Drive API: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk